# scroll gallery how to make it infinite loop instead of running back to the first

Tags: jquery

..Hi guys im really new to jquery and im having a hard time fixing this issue. The issue is... I want an infinite loop and not the effect of running back to the first content.

```
function initCarousel() {
jQuery('.link-block').scrollGallery({
    mask: 'div.mask',
    slider: 'div.slideset',
    slides: 'div.slide',
    btnPrev: 'a.prev',
    btnNext: 'a.next',
    autoRotation: true,
//displayTime: 5000,
    circularRotation: true,
    switchTime: 3000,
    animSpeed: 500
```

............

```
    // jquery plugin
$.fn.scrollGallery = function(opt){
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).data('ScrollGallery', new ScrollGallery($.extend(opt,{holder:this})));
    });
};
}(jQuery));
```

hope someone here can help :)

Comment: I fixed the code formatting on that last line of code, but what does that `}(jQuery));` actually belong to?

Comment: jsfiddle or full html code will help.

Comment: One year later, do you have any idea how to do so? I just ran into the same problem inside someone else's code. I don't have any clue yet... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Although providing a jsfiddle would help confirm this, I have a feeling the plugin you're using doesn't support the "infinite loop" effect you're after.

The following plugin functions with the 'infinite loop' effect, , and **seems** to be designed to 'plug in' to the same HTML structure that the ScrollGallery plugin work from. Again seeing the original HTML, rest of the JS, would help.

```
function initCycleCarousel() {
    jQuery('.link-block').scrollAbsoluteGallery({
        mask: 'div.mask',
        slider: 'div.slideset',
        slides: 'div.slide',
        btnPrev: 'a.prev',
        btnNext: 'a.next',
        pauseOnHover: true,
        maskAutoSize: true,
        autoRotation: true,
        switchTime: 3000,
        animSpeed: 500
    });
}
```

The plugin itself can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Mue6k8A4). You'll need to include it in your javascript too.